# Hide and show mouse cursor after a particular interval of time

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse, visual-c++

I want to hide my mouse after 5 seconds if my system mouse is not moved. I asked in this question [check mouse activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611382/how-to-check-mouse-is-not-moved-from-last-5-seconds)

Now I'm able to check the activity of mouse and change cursor ...
My code is:

```
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "resource.h"

HCURSOR hCurBlank; 
HCURSOR hCurstandard;

void blank_cursor()
{
     hCurBlank =  LoadCursor(NULL,  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1)); //loading a cursor from a file
     HCURSOR hcCopyblnkcur = CopyCursor(hCurBlank);
    BOOL bret=  SetSystemCursor( hcCopyblnkcur, 32512); //will set the cursor by using load cursor from file

}

void default_cursor()
{

            hCurstandard = LoadCursor(NULL,  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR2));
            HCURSOR hcursdef = CopyCursor(hCurstandard);
            HCURSOR hCurStandard = GetCursor();
            //SetCursor(hCurstandard);
        BOOL brets =SetSystemCursor( hcursdef, 32512);


}
void determine_idle_time()
{
    LASTINPUTINFO lif;   //Typedef for last input info will result in cb and dwtime
    lif.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
    DWORD tickCount, idleCount;   // Double word value


    for (;;)
    {
        GetLastInputInfo(&lif);    //It will check the system's last activity module
        tickCount = GetTickCount();    //GetTickCount will get the time from which system has been started and will be continue
        //upto 49 days
        idleCount = (tickCount - lif.dwTime) / 1000;  //This will return the time in the seconds. It will check for 
        //starting time and the last input info time. so the last activity time will be returned

        std::cout<< "Idle time: " << idleCount << " seconds." << std::endl;


        // Sleep for some milliseconds before the next output.
        DWORD randomized_time = rand() % (800 - 600 + 1) + 10;   //rand()%(800-300+1) + 300;
        //rand will pick any random value and this will generate a double value
        Sleep(randomized_time);
        //Sleep(500);
        if(idleCount>10)
        {
            blank_cursor();

        }
        else 
        {
            default_cursor();

        }
    }
}

int main() {
   srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
   determine_idle_time();


}
```

This code can change my cursors but If I'm getting the arrow cursor, It's changing in busy cursor.
I can see that SetSystemCursor is not working properly, with which I'm unable to change the cursor image.
I want to replace my cursor with a blank cursor after 10 seconds or 5 second and then on mouse move it becomes arrow.

problem: Arrow cursor becomes busy and hide is working fine.
I can't use LoadCursorFromFile() because It'll read from file not from resource that will create a problem in my release.
Please share your experience..

Comment: Have you tried just using `SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, NULL));`?

Comment: Not a complete dupe, but some cautionary tales about SetSystemCursor and a way to avoid it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541014/hiding-system-cursor

Comment: @Daboyzuk, I've tried this but it's not working.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I've used this and also written in my question when I use LoadCursorFromFile(), It works fine. But it needs direct .cur or .ani file and I've my image in resource that is unable to do it.

Comment: The docs for [LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx) don't say it can take NULL for the first parameter except for certain values of the second parameter. You're meant to give it the module instance handle in other cases.

Comment: @JonathanPotter,For first parameter it says "A handle to an instance of the module whose executable file contains the cursor to be loaded. ". I think NULL should work. If I'm wrong then should I make an HINSTANCE here? Please suggest.

Comment: How is NULL a handle to an instance of the module? Try `GetModuleHandle(0)` maybe, or the instance handle that's passed to your `WinMain` function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Thanks I just used GetModuleHandle(NULL) and it works fine.