# In C#, WPF, could I hide my cursors in all windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

everyone.

When I develop an application using C#, WPF. I want to hide my cursor in some special area. No matter which application/window on top, the cursor is always hiding.

In WPF Window, normally, we use

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.None;
```

But this one could not solve my problem.

I want this situation:

I open my window, the cursor disappears in my window. And then I open a notepad on top of my window, the cursor disappears in the notepad too.

This one is able to do or not? Thank you.

Comment: The cursor is controlled by whichever window the mouse is over, i.e., whichever window is on top at that spot on the screen. So if you want a particular area of the screen not to have a cursor, you'd have to make your window [Topmost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx). Would that cover what you're looking for?

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks for your answer. This is not what I want. If the window is Topmost, all others windows will be invisible. But I want all other windows appearing without the real cursor.

Comment: @cindywmiao when do you want to re-enable the cursor? Re-enable within your application or anywhere?

Comment: @cindywmiao you could use this to hide system pointer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541014/hiding-system-cursor

Answer (score 3):

You also can use win32 dll.

```
internal static class WinCursors
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowCursor(bool bShow);


    internal static void ShowCursor()
    {
        while (ShowCursor(true) < 0)
        {

        }
    }

    internal static void HideCursor()
    {
        while (ShowCursor(false) >= 0) //使用这个方法可以关闭光标
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it area is the same on each Form, you could create a custom BaseForm (or similar) which derives from Form, and put a Label on there and use its MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to hide the cursor.

All your forms can then derive from BaseForm rather than Form so that they all have this area.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I edited my question more clear, the MouseEnter and MouseLeave seem not work for my situation.

Comment: Okay, I suspect that the short answer here is no. Obviously, Notepad is a separate application completely and there's no way of accessing its properties from your application (and even if there were, it'll be written in C++ or C, so there'll be no Form object etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Simply inside your `mouseEnter` event use a `cursor hide`

```
    private void splitContainer1_Panel2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Cursor.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot.But it seems not work for my situation. I want open my window, cursor disappears in my window. Then open a notepad on top my window, the cursor disappears in notepad too.

Comment: I would guess it is simply because it detects the `mouseEnter` event even you place a notepad on top of it. This should be can solve by creating a `custom panel : panel` or also known as `double panel`

Comment: I cant find ` Cursor.Hide` for Cursor is type.

Comment: **System.Windows.Input.Cursor** doesn't have method "Hide", "Show" or so. If you indeed intend to hide/show cursor on your window, be aware of two rules:  1) Cursor event become untouchable if you set your window background to **transparent**;  2) You can either set **Mouse.Cursor=Cursors.None** on your .cs or append attribute **Cursor="None"** to your Controls on XAML, based on rule 1. Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Window Class's event
Activted, FocusableChanged or other relative events

Answer (score 0):

The window on top is the one that controls the mouse cursor. So the only way to do this is to put your window on top, likely by making it [`Topmost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to still be able to see the windows underneath it, you can make your window semitransparent. Set the [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true` and then set your window's background color to a semitransparent color. (You can't make it 100% transparent, because WPF treats full transparency as meaning "there's nothing here, so send mouse events to the next window behind me"; but you can do something like `#01000000` that's so close to transparent that nobody will notice it.)