# How to calculate height (width) between 2 pixels on screen?

Tags: c#, position, pixel, graphic

I was asked to do an app (preferably in C#) that is able to do something like this:

1. I run the app (e.g.: it is active on my active monitor)
2. Then I click 2 pixels (not necessarily exactly the pixel, the epsilon would be +-3px)
3. The program would compute, or show at the bottom, height(width) between them

Something like "positionShower" in a simple paint, except I pick 2 pixels on whole display (doesn't matter if it's in an active window or completely out of it) but it wouldn't need any other program to be ran at the same time.

Any help ? I wasn't really able to search for anything similar.

Comment: `var height = Math.Abs(Point2.Y - Point1.Y);` and `var width = Math.Abs(Point2.X - Point1.X);`

Comment: @SaniHuttunen would I need to code some eventHandler on the mouse clicks, and implement the visualization of my display ? Sorry if it sounds "lameish" but I'm rather new to this kind of problems.

Comment: @SpikeX I'm trying to figure out the logic in the process before actually doing anything, because I've no idea.

Comment: @n0win0u: Yes. Get the click events and record the cursor position for both clicks (`Point1` and `Point2`) then calculate the width and height.

Comment: When you say 'app in C#', is this Winforms, WPF, a web app etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to hook the low level mouse events globaly, see [LowLevelMouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx), [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) and other functions you will find below in the sample code.

To test the sample, please create a new Windows Forms project and add three labels on to the main form, like this:

[image: form design]

And replace the code in Form1.cs with the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _proc = HookCallback;

            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        }

        // This method is called for each global mouse event
        private IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 &&
                MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                if (isFirstClick)
                {
                    firstClickMouseStruct = hookStruct;
                    label1.Text = "First click: " + hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y;
                }
                else
                {
                    secondClickMouseStruct = hookStruct;
                    label2.Text = "Second click: " + secondClickMouseStruct.pt.x + ", " + secondClickMouseStruct.pt.y;
                    label3.Text = "Height: " + Math.Abs(secondClickMouseStruct.pt.y - firstClickMouseStruct.pt.y)
                        + ", Width: " + Math.Abs(secondClickMouseStruct.pt.x - firstClickMouseStruct.pt.x);
                }
                isFirstClick = !isFirstClick;
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private MSLLHOOKSTRUCT firstClickMouseStruct;
        private MSLLHOOKSTRUCT secondClickMouseStruct;
        private bool isFirstClick = true;

        private LowLevelMouseProc _proc = null;
        private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can click by left mouse button inside or outside your form (on desktop or on other windows) and the application will hook the clicks, check the mouse positions and calculate Height and Width as needed:

[image: result]

Comment: the it seems it does nothing for me, I can click all I want, nothing happens. Any advice ? (labels stay untouched)

Comment: fixed alrdy, the Form1 didn't load an event of the loading itself. Works now, thank you once again

Comment: Is it possible, to force windows to not change mouseOverEffects while this app is visible/on ? I mean I run the app, i can click twice, but the cursor stays default everywhere (not only in the form). I've thought about making an overlay (with opacity 0) to force some onMouseOver effect, but the user wouldn't be able to, e.g.: switch tabs in browser. (I've made the form mostTop). Is this possible? Also, is there a way to create small magnifying glass around the cursor, while making it default. But the priority is definitely the default cursor. ty

Comment: I'm NOT sure it's a good idea to override the system cursor, better think about the overlay. Otherwise, please check this post, maybe it will help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541014/hiding-system-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int distance;
    Point location = new Point(); 
    Point location2 = new Point();
    private void FormClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(location == new Point())
        {
            location = Form.MousePosition;
        }
        else if (location2 == new Point())
        {
            location2 = Form.MousePosition;
            distance = location2.X - location.X;
            location = new Point();
            location2 = new Point();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will only work in bounds of the application form. The initial question is about a whole desktop, regardless whether there is any active window or not.

Comment: no the question clearly stated you could have a full screen active window. "(doesn't matter if it's in an active window or completely out of it)"

Comment: "...or completely out of it"

Comment: I understood that as he doesn't care if the windows has to be active or not.

Comment: you solution is better, just maybe overkill:)

Comment: guys thank you both for helping me, @Alexey was right, he got it exactly what I meant, but I believe I will also implement your solution boomoto but on other task I was assigned. I still have lots to learn, especially handling events. Thanks again.